# Different names for same HTML element

Tags: html, widget, custom-element

I am renaming a custom HTML element, however I would like to preserve the old element name as well. I was hoping to be able to do the following:

```
import Widget from "./widget";
customElements.define("old-widget-name", Widget);
customElements.define("new-widget-name", Widget);
```

However I get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this
> constructor has already been used with this registry

Is there any elegant way to do this? I could copy the code in `widget.js` to another file but that seems a bit dodgy.

Comment: You can't UNdefine a Custom Element, so I presume the error is caused because you already defined the element in your widget file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import Widget from "./widget";
customElements.define("old-widget-name", class extends Widget {});
customElements.define("new-widget-name", Widget);
```

You could even expand on this, adding some code to the extending class that warns the user to stop using the old name, or whatever:

```
import Widget from "./widget";

class OldWidget extends Widget {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.warn("Please use new-widget-name instead of old-widget-name from now on!");
  }
}

customElements.define("old-widget-name", OldWidget);
customElements.define("new-widget-name", Widget);
```